# spring multiple endpoints with same request params

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have a RestController.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/children")
public class ChildController {

    private ChildService childService;

    @Autowired
    public ChildController(ChildService childService) {
        this.childService = childService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<ChildDto> list() {
        List<ChildDto> response = childService.list();
        return response;
    }


    @GetMapping(params = "parentId")
    public List<ChildDto> getChildrenByParent(@RequestParam Integer parentId) {
        List<ChildDto> response = childService.getChildrenByParent(parentId);
        return response;
    }

    @GetMapping(params = {"fullName", "age", "parentId"})
    public List<ChildDto> getFilteredChildren(@RequestParam String fullName,
                                              @RequestParam Integer age,
                                              @RequestParam Integer parentId) {
        List<ChildDto> response = childService.getFilteredChildren(fullName, age, parentId);
        return response;
    }
}
```

In my business logic in service it's should be okay if some param in `getFilteredChildren` is not sent, but I have an issue when I sent request to

`http://localhost:8080/api/children?age=10&parentId=3`

it' processed by `getChildrenByParent`, not by `getFilteredChildren`

What can I do except sending all params like

`http://localhost:8080/api/children?age=10&parentId=3&fullName=`

or changing path for some of endpoints

Answer (score 2):

You are not reaching `getFilteredChildren()` because by default, the request parameteres are all required. As some are missing, this endpoint is discarded. So, one thing you could try, is making some of the parameters optional:

```
@GetMapping(params = {"fullName", "age", "parentId"})
public List<ChildDto> getFilteredChildren(@RequestParam(required = false) String fullName,
                                          @RequestParam Integer age,
                                          @RequestParam Integer parentId) {
    List<ChildDto> response = childService.getFilteredChildren(fullName, age, parentId);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct mapping.
If you have a query string params then use single mapping and based on it's value call the appropriate service method

```
@GetMapping
    public List<ChildDto> getChildren(@RequestParam(name = "fullName", required = false) String fullName,
            @RequestParam(name = "age", required = false) Integer age,
            @RequestParam(name = "parentId", required = false) Integer parentId) {
        List<ChildDto> response = null;
        if (null == fullName && null == age && null == parentId) {
            response = childService.list();
        } else if (null == fullName && null == age) {
            response = childService.getChildrenByParent(parentId);
        } else {
            response = childService.getFilteredChildren(fullName, age, parentId);
        }
        return response;
    }
```